# Annotation equivalent of <tx:jta-transaction-manager/> for Java EE environments

Tags: java, spring, annotations

How can I achieve something similar to this:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="datasSource" 
     jndi-name="jdbc/dataSourceName" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>
```

Using annotations?

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
      // What goes here?
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager txManager() {
      // What goes here?
    }
}
```

I've seen a lot of examples with `DataSourceTransactionManager` and `BasicDataSource`, but I couldn't find a equivalent annotation driven configuration (that finds the container `UserTransaction`, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I am aware of is to replicate the behavior of namespace parsers of these custom namespaces.

So, `<jee:jndi-lookup>` is handled by `org.springframework.ejb.config.JndiLookupBeanDefinitionParser` and ultimate creates a bean which is an instance of `JndiObjectFactoryBean` with the passed in attributes.

Similarly, `<tx:jta-transaction-manager/>` is handled by `org.springframework.transaction.config.JtaTransactionManagerBeanDefinitionParser` and based on the runtime environment, returns a specific instance of class.

A neat feature of Spring 4 that you can use is `@Conditional`(reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html)). With @Conditional and using a [Spring-Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) Conditional implementation called `ConditionalOnClass`(reference [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html)), you can replicate the behavior of `<tx...` something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(name="weblogic.transaction.UserTransaction")
public class WebLogicTxMgrConfig {

    @Bean
    public JtaTransactionManager txManager() {
        return new WebLogicJtaTransactionManager();
    }

}
```

I know this is not a complete answer, but hopefully should help you create the relevant configuration.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Biju. So, if I have a fixed application server I must find which `JtaTransactionManager` it uses and build it manually right? How about the DataSource, should I just use a `JndiDataSourceLookup` object instantiated manually?